# Как быстро определить наличие строки в файле, при этом не засорять ОЗУ?

Tags: c#

Есть код. Он находится в цикле. Каждый раз генерируется случайная строка. Его переделывать не нужно, это просто пример:

```
bool F = true;
HashSet<string> HS = new(File.ReadAllLines(path));
Random rnd = new();
string Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
int Length= 42;
while (F)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new(Lenght - 1);
  int Position = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < Lenght; i++)
  {
    Position = rnd.Next(0, Alphabet.Lenght - 1);
    sb.Append(Alphabet[Position]);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(sb);
  if (HS.Contains(sb.ToString())
  {
    F = false;
  }
}
```

Также есть текстовый файл (*250 Мб+*, загружается в начале, строки в нём никогда точь в точь не повторяются, но все начинаются на "7L"):

```
7LbOa94610KaBUfMR945BaQiaPxmvvzg92640HaMCO
7L9MzBxk8F4anfi284B639Ksmgb72laHsJOF72Mapx
7L2VzMqPie96MzvBROha724Hsu8R1N09BxM7S6a7w0
7LXxos73JsgfoHzHs9264HdvxppalndGd629HskUqm
7LNdifvaSj39Hd6ri3Jd7wvfisgskdY7xbdkGsjcNx
...
```

Мне нужно при каждой генерации проверять, есть ли сгенерированная строка в файле.

Но такой метод не вариант, жрёт слишком много ОЗУ (получается *1,1 Гб* занятой *ОЗУ* из *~250 Мб* файла). И это я не использую файлы от *~3Гб*.

Можно как-то экономнее использовать данные файла, чтобы и скорость проверки строк была высокой?
P.S.: Попробовал использовать алгоритм - фильтр Блума. Первое время он работал отлично, но с более большими файлами количество коллизий  тоже только увеличивается. Также мне не нужно никуда добавлять только что сгенерированные строки, только проверка.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149286/discussion-on-question-by-evil12boy-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте дерево поиска. Упростим задачу: алфавит: `[A, B, C, D]` длинна слова - до 4 символов. Создайте структуру в файловой системе:

```
+--- A
|    +--- A
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    +--- B
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    +--- C
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    \--- D
|         +--- A
|         +--- B
|         +--- C
|         \--- D
+--- B
|    +--- A
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    +--- B
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    +--- C
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    \--- D
|         +--- A
|         +--- B
|         +--- C
|         \--- D
+--- C
|    +--- A
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    +--- B
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    +--- C
|    |    +--- A
|    |    +--- B
|    |    +--- C
|    |    \--- D
|    \--- D
|         +--- A
|         +--- B
|         +--- C
|         \--- D
+--- D
     +--- A
     |    +--- A
     |    +--- B
     |    +--- C
     |    \--- D
     +--- B
     |    +--- A
     |    +--- B
     |    +--- C
     |    \--- D
     +--- C
     |    +--- A
     |    +--- B
     |    +--- C
     |    \--- D
     \--- D
          +--- A
          +--- B
          +--- C
          \--- D
```

В папке `B/A/C` храните файл со всеми строками, которые начинаются на `BAC` (без префикса). Таким образом, в файле по пути `B/A/C` будут только строки `[A, B, C, D]`, которые соответствуют строкам `["BACA", "BACB", "BACC", "BACD"]`.
Чтобы проверить, что вашей строки нет, просто перейдите на нужный файл и проверьте его содержимое.
Если большая часть дерева заполнена - никакое сжатие не поможет. Энтропия данных очень велика (по крайней мере исходя из того примера, который вы предоставили). Если вы предоставите больше информации о данных, возможно, будут иметь место оптимизации.

Comment: Давайте я немного изменю вопрос, одну минуту.

Comment: @Evil12Boy если вы закончили изменять вопрос, этот ответ всё ещё остаётся жизнеспособным. Вам только нужно разбить "файл который загружается в начале скрипта" на несколько файлов как я сказал.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [фильтр Блума](https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/541378/), чтобы быстро определить, содержится ли ваша строка среди уже сгенерированных значений. В частности, поскольку ваш алфавит ограничен, используйте в качестве хэш функций порядковый номер символа из вашего слова в алфавите. Идея такая же как и с файлами. Если хоть один хэш не совпадает - значит слова нет в наборе и можно его добавить. Работает даже если слова разной длинны.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте базу данных, ведь она будет быстрее любого неструктурированного файла. Представьте, например, что вы отсортировали все слова в файле и используете бинарный поиск, чтобы определить, есть ли слово в файле. Это очень эффективно. Но вот, вы определили, что файл не содержит очередного слова. Что вы будете делать, чтобы добавить слово в файл и **сохранить его сортировку**? Правильно, вы будете вынуждены добавить слово в середину файла, что является **очень** дорогостоящим как по памяти так и по времени для такого огромного файла. Если бы речь шла о базе данных, вы могли бы создать иерархические таблицы и вставка нового слова сводилась бы к добавлению новой записи в очередную таблицу, что выполняется за O(1) (амортизированно). Поиск же будет осуществляться эффективно средствами самой базы данных.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [радужные таблицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), чтобы выяснить, что слова нет в файле. Для применения этого метода вам нужно предварительно сгенерировать радужные таблицы из вашего файла (и, возможно, дополнять по мере необходимости), чтобы использовать их для быстрого выяснения, есть ли слово в таком большом массиве данных. Этот метод немного более гибок, чем фильтр Блума, поскольку он позволяет заранее определить отношение память/производительность для вашей задачи, путём генерации радужной таблицы необходимой конфигурации.

По большому счёту, все решения сводятся к одной простой идее **"Разделяй и властвуй"**